# id passed down through props doesn't display related data

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that has another component. Basically, If I hover over the name, I want its related details to be populated below. so far I have been successful in just passing the id, but that id isn't much use as the data isn't relevant. I don't know what am I missing

Following is my code

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <ul class="pokemon-list">
        <li  v-for="(character, index) in filteredPokemon" :key="index">
         <!-- <router-link :to="'/pokemon/'+ character.url.slice(0,-1).split('/').pop()"> -->
            <a href='#' @mouseover="greet(character.url)">
              {{character.name}} 
            </a>
          <!-- </router-link> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
       <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search Pokemon">

       <SinglePokemon :name="characters.name" :pid="id"/>
     </div>

</template>

<script>
import SinglePokemon from "./singlePokemon.vue"
export default {
  name: 'pokemon',
  components: {
    SinglePokemon
  },
  data () {
    return {
      id: '',
      characters: [],
      charactersDetails : [],
      search : ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    greet: function(id){
      this.id = id.slice(0,-1).split('/').pop();
    }
  },
  mounted(){
      let total = this.$http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon`)
        .then((data)=>{
         this.characters = data.body.results;
        }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err);
        })
  },
    computed: {
       filteredPokemon: function(){
        return this.characters.filter((character)=> {
            return character.name.match(this.search)
        })
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to display related info from this component when id is passed

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="details">
            <li>
                Name: {{charactersDetails.name}} {{pid}}
            </li>
            <li>
                Abilities: {{charactersDetails.abilities}}
            </li>
            <li>
                Height: {{charactersDetails.height}}
            </li>
            <li>
                Weight: {{charactersDetails.weight}}
            </li>
            <li>
                Species: {{charactersDetails.species}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['name', 'pid'],
    data(){
        return {
            id: this.pid,
            charactersDetails : {
                name : "",
                abilities : "",
                height: "",
                weight: "",
                species: ""
            }
        }
    },
    mounted(){
            let results = this.$http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.id}`)
                .then((results)=>{
                return results.json()
                }).then(data => {
                    this.charactersDetails.abilities = data.abilities[0].ability.name; //ability
                    this.charactersDetails.name = data.name //name
                    this.charactersDetails.weight =data.weight //weight
                    this.charactersDetails.height = data.height //height
                    this.charactersDetails.species = data.species.name //species name
                })
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The child component will only be mounted once, when it is first created. At that point the value of `pid` will be an empty string. You should see the corresponding HTTP request going out in the Network tab of your developer tools. The request should succeed but I imagine you'll then get an error in the console because the data returned doesn't have an `abilities` property.

Subsequent changes to the parent's `id` property will be passed down as the `pid` prop of the child. That should cause the template to update with the new `pid` value but it won't load any other data from the server.

There are a few ways you could fix this.

One solution is to introduce a `watch` on the `pid`:

```js
watch: {
  pid: 'loadDetails'
},

created () {
  this.loadDetails()
},

methods: {
  loadDetails () {
    // TODO: You may want alternative behaviour when pid is empty
    if (!this.pid) {
      return
    }

    // Note: this.pid, not this.id
    this.$http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.pid}`)
      // ... the rest of your code for loading goes here
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. I've changed `this.id` to `this.pid` when building the URL. You should also remove the `id` property from the `data` of the child component. Having a `data` property that duplicates a prop is unnecessary and can lead to bugs.
2. I've moved the code from your `mounted` hook into a method called `loadDetails`. The `mounted` hook can be removed.
3. Instead of loading the data within the `mounted` hook I've loaded it from the `created` hook. It doesn't really matter which you use but `created` feels more correct to me. Alternatively you could set the `immediate` flag on the `watch` so that it is automatically triggers when the component is first created.
4. In the current use case trying to load the data when the component is first created is irrelevant anyway as the `pid` is initially empty. However it is better to write the component to work in general, not just in the specific case you're facing.
5. Inside `loadDetails` I have chosen to bail out when the `pid` is missing. That will leave the previous details in place if the `pid` changes back to empty. That may not currently be a problem but it may not be the correct behaviour in the general case.
6. I've removed the `let results =` part. It wasn't doing anything.

The other way you could solve this is to use a `key`.

```html
<SinglePokemon :name="characters.name" :pid="id" :key="id" />
```

Using a `key` will tell Vue to destroy the component and create a new one when the `id` changes. The new component will run its `mounted` hook, so your loading code will be run.

This may seem like a simpler solution but it relies on the parent of your component to do some magic to get it to work. The child component itself is rather fragile. The earlier solution would generally be preferable as it makes the child more robust and doesn't need any special help from the parent component.